# PayPal sandbox API don't allow buyers to log in

Tags: java, android, android-studio, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i am working on android studio developing mobile application. i have a payment feature and i integrated PayPal sandbox and when user clicks check out the PayPal page appears. however, when any buyers tries to log in using the appeared page it "incorrect username/password. please try again" although i am sure it is correct and tried multiple accounts and one of them has a valid real credit card but same output. I wonder why this happens? please can someone help me as soon as possible.

this what appears when user tries to log in:
[screen shot of PayPal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RSlc.png)

three java classes are related to payment part are provided:

confirmOrder.java:

```
package com.example.my1stapplication;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.example.my1stapplication.config.Config;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class confirmOrder extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText district, streetName, houseNo, phoneNo;
    Button checkout;

    DatabaseReference ordersref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
    final HashMap<String, Object> ordersMap=new HashMap<>();
public static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE=7171;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX).clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
 //Double totalPrice=getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice",0);


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_order);

        Double totalPrice=getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice",0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        district = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.district);
        streetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetName);
        houseNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.houseNo);
        phoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
        checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout);
        String buyerID = getIntent().getStringExtra("buyerID");
        // Double totalPrice=getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice",0);
        //HashMap cart=(HashMap) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cart");


        checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String district1 = district.getText().toString();
                String streetName1 = district.getText().toString();
                String houseNo1 = district.getText().toString();
                String phoneNo1 = district.getText().toString();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(district1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(district1)
                        && !TextUtils.isEmpty(district1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(district1)) {

                    Double totalPrice = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice", 0);
                    HashMap<String, Object> cart = (HashMap<String, Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cart");
                    String Orderid = ordersref.push().getKey();
                    ordersMap.put("orderID", Orderid);
                    ordersMap.put("totalPrice", (totalPrice));
                    ordersMap.put("buyerID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    ordersMap.put("district", district1);
                    ordersMap.put("streetName", streetName1);
                    ordersMap.put("houseNo", houseNo1);
                    ordersMap.put("phoneNo", phoneNo1);
                    ordersMap.put("paied", false);
                    ordersMap.put("shipped", false);
                    ordersMap.put("takenFromOwner", false);
                    //ordersMap.put("inCart", adapter);
                    ordersref.child(Orderid).updateChildren(ordersMap);
                    ordersref.child(Orderid).child("cart").updateChildren(cart);

                    processPayment();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void processPayment(){

        Double totalPrice=getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice",0);
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment =new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(totalPrice),"USD", "Pay for the material/s" , PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        Double totalPrice=getIntent().getDoubleExtra("totalPrice",0);


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null) {

                    try {

                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, PaymentDetails.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails).putExtra("PaymentAmount", totalPrice));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }

                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Payment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }


    }
}
```

PaymentDetails.java:

```
package com.example.my1stapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Intent;
import org.json.JSONException;
public class PaymentDetails extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView txtId,txtAmount,txtStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_details);


        txtId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtId);
        txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        txtAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);

        Intent intent=getIntent();

        try{

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails"));
        showDetails(jsonObject.getJSONObject("response"),intent.getStringExtra("PaymentAmount"));



        }
        catch (JSONException e){
e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }


    private void showDetails(JSONObject response , String paymentAmount) throws JSONException {

try {
    txtId.setText(response.getString("id"));
    txtStatus.setText(response.getString("status"));
    txtAmount.setText("SR"+paymentAmount);
}

catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

}
```

Config.java:

```
package com.example.my1stapplication.config;

public class Config {
    public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = "AR1bLXBzCYYWa4BCkEyTTcbijrtWPh9u15b3sxQbHQZ-ymhEonDq9zwMo1CqqM95fwHPp-pNjbRF99Am";
}
```

Comment: @randstraw can you help me

Comment: if there is any way to use any type of account that does not show this problem please tell me. i only need a way to test it because it is just a college course project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to log into a PayPal Sandbox page, you must use a PayPal Sandbox ( www.sandbox.paypal.com ) account , not a live ( www.paypal.com ) account.

You can create as many PayPal Sandbox accounts as you need within https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts

Their email identifiers are fictitious and can be anything not previously used in sandbox. No real emails are ever sent to those addresses; instead, there is a Notifications tab on the left of developer.paypal.com